# How to get lookup field choices in CSOM?

Tags: list, lookup-column

I have a lookup field which is connected to listB. In listB I have for example 3 items: A, B, C. I would like to get all these items by lookup field in CSOM. Is this possible?

I have now this code:

```
var listA = ClientContext.Site.RootWeb.GetListByTitle(SharePointListName);

            if (list != null)
            {
                FieldLookup field = ClientContext.CastTo<FieldLookup>(listA.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle(lookupFieldColumnName));

                ClientContext.Load(field);
                ClientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                // some logic to get all choices from this lookup field, I expect A, B, C from listB
            }
```

Comment: Have you tried accessing the list via the FieldLookup.LookupList property, example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26991407/how-to-retrieve-associated-list-name-from-a-fieldlookupvalue-sharepoint-2013-cso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
var listA = ClientContext.Site.RootWeb.GetListByTitle(SharePointListName);

var field = ClientContext.CastTo<FieldLookup>(listA.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle(lookupFieldColumnName));
ClientContext.Load(field);
ClientContext.ExecuteQuery();

var lkField = field as FieldLookup;
ClientContext.Load(lkField, f => f.LookupList);
ClientContext.ExecuteQuery();

var listB = ClientContext.Site.RootWeb.Lists.GetById(new Guid(lkField.LookupList));

var itemColl = listB.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
ClientContext.Load(itemColl);
ClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

I could use this code

```
var listA = ClientContext.Site.RootWeb.GetListByTitle(SharePointListName);

var field = ClientContext.CastTo<FieldLookup>(listA.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle(lookupFieldColumnName));
ClientContext.Load(field);
ClientContext.ExecuteQuery();

var choices = ((FieldMultiChoice)field.TypedObject).Choices
```